# What is the difference between "drumo" and "tamburo"?

Tags: word-usage

Can somebody explain what the difference between *drumo* and *tamburo* is?

Comment: Do you mean "tamburo"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Drumo* refers to a drum set, while *tamburo* refers to a single drum. From the PIV:

- Tamburo: Instrumento, konsistanta el malplena cilindro, kies ambaŭ bazaj flankoj estas fermitaj per du maldikaj streĉitaj folioj el ledo, kiujn oni frapas per bastonetoj
- Drumo: Parto de ĵazorkestro aŭ popgrupo, konsistanta el diversaj tamburoj k cimbaloj, k donanta la ritman fundamenton